# Fetch records from PhpMyAdmin with max year

Tags: php, mysql, select, phpmyadmin

I have below table

```
+--------------+-----------+
| serial no    |  isNew    |
+--------------+-----------+
| 630401A      |  2014     |
| 630401B      |  2014     |
| 630401A      |  2013     |
| 630401B      |  2013     |
| 630401C      |  2013     |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Now the thing is I want to select records as per isNew column. As you can see that serial no is same and isNew is different in 2 cases and in on case there is only record for serial number.

So I want output like

```
+--------------+-----------+
| serial no    |  isNew    |
+--------------+-----------+
| 630401A      |  2014     |
| 630401B      |  2014     |
| 630401C      |  2013     |
+--------------+-----------+
```

I hope I am very clear to display my table and result I want.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from TABLENAME group by serialno order by isNew DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

`GROUP BY` statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to `group` the `result-set`

Use `group by serialno`

```
select * from table group by serialno order by isNew DESC
```

Comment: it's fetching only two columns 
1. 630401A      |  2014
2. 630401A      |  2013

Comment: select * from table group by serialno

Answer (score 0):

```
select `serial no`, max(isNew) from table group by `serial no`
```